# Probability of randomly selecting one student from each of three cities

Tags: probability

The geographical distribution of hometown of some 80 students at DLSU-D is given as: 50 from Cavite, 10 from Laguna, and 20 from Manila. Suppose three students are selected. Find the probability that they all come from the three places.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say

$P=\frac{50\cdot20\cdot10}{{80 \choose 3}}$

Comment: 375 is the answer ?

Comment: $\frac{50\cdot20\cdot10}{{80 \choose 3}}\doteq 0.122$

Comment: can you help me in this ? McGyver is faced with the problem of opening a safe with 10 buttons numbered from 0 to 9. The safe can be opened by pressing three buttons, not necessarily distinct, in correct order. What is the probability that McGyver will hit the right combination?

Comment: It can not. Give a separate question.